# ООП вызвать 2 метода подряд

Tags: php

Видел в примерах что можно вызвать 2 метода подряд, но почему то у меня не получается

```
$curl = new Yandex;
$curl->setOrderId('7986730')->getStatus();
```

Ошибка

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStatus() on null in /var/www/html/yandex/token.php on line 93
```

Comment: setOrderId возвращает null, а у null нету метода getStatus(). И это не вызов двух методов одновременно, а просто 2 вызова. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но многопоточность в php еще не завезли

Comment: @Lofectr многопоточность в пыхе уж лет 10 :)

Answer (score 4):

метод setOrderId должен возвращать объект $this ,а у тебя null. В php 8 можно обработать это так

```
$curl->setOrderId('7986730')?->getStatus();
```

Comment: думаю для ответа достаточно было того, что метод setOrderId должен возвращать $this :)